# How to run test in IE browser using OxygenHQ?

Tags: automation, ui-automation

I want to run a simple test using OxygenHQ, of opening wikipedia and then search for hello world. The script written is working fine for Chrome and Firefox but in case of IE mutiple windows are opening without the page and then it fails eventually.

Is there any way to fix this? I went through the docs provided at http://docs.oxygenhq.org/guide-web-intro.html but could not get a concrete answer on why this is only happening for IE. Here is a console output and screenshot for reference.

Console Output :

```
Initializing...
Starting iteration #1
UNKNOWN_ERROR - undefined: args[0].endsWith is not a function at line 1Test finished with status --> FAILED
```

[image]

**Details**:

- Browser: Internet Explorer
- Version: 11.535.18362.0
- OS: Windows 10

Comment: Please post logs. `Help -> Open Log file`. Note that logs will contain script content, so you might want to remove any sensitive information first.
P.S. oh, didn't notice the post date. You might want to update to new version if still relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be connected to your internet settings

1. make sure that the IE screen size is 100%
2. make sure all Internet options in Security Tab (Internet, Local Internet etc') are either with the Enable protected mode on or off (should be the same for all)
   see picture

Have a look again at the Oxygen web site, it has had a major facelift and a lot of new content

[image]

Comment: Keeping the screen size (zoom) to 100% is current way to do the automation. Thanks :)